# Force DropDownList to use list instead of ActionSheet for mobile

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm working on an iPad app using Kendo and the DropDownList is throwing an ActionSheet. I'd like to force it to use the Web UI list style. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I was able to hack together a solution. Here's a function that accepts a kendoMobileView as the argument and applies the fix.

```js
//Hack to force dropdowns to act like comboboxes in mobile!
 utils.fix.dropdownlists = function(view) {
      var dropdowns = view.element.find("[data-role='dropdownlist']");
      //Iterate through dropdown elements
      _.each(dropdowns, function(item){
        var comp = $(item).data("kendoDropDownList");
        if(comp && comp.popup) {
          comp.popup.bind("open", function(event){
            event.sender.element.parent().removeClass("km-popup km-widget");
            if(event.sender.element.parent().hasClass("km-popup")) {
              //Prevent default open animation.
              //Then remove classes and open the popup programitcally
              //Easy peasy, Lemon squeezy
              event.preventDefault();
              event.sender.element.parent().removeClass("km-popup km-widget");
              setTimeout(function(){
                event.sender.open();
              },0);
            }
          });
        }
      });
 }
```